# How to get unrecognized backends in Matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, pyqt, qt5

I'm trying to embed matplotlib canvas in PyQt5 application on Ubuntu 14.04.

The following worked on OSX but returned an error on Ubuntu: `matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")`

Error:

`ValueError: Unrecognized backend string "qt5agg": valid strings are ['GTK3Agg', 'GTKCairo', 'MacOSX', 'pdf', 'Qt4Agg', 'agg', 'template', 'cairo', 'TkAgg', 'GTK', 'gdk', 'CocoaAgg', 'GTKAgg', 'WebAgg', 'WX', 'ps', 'svg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'WXAgg', 'pgf', 'emf']`

How can I add "qt5agg" backend to this environment or is there any way to make Qt5 application work with other backends available listed above?

Thanks.

Comment: Which versions of python and matplotlib do you have installed? You may have a matplotlib version prior to PyQt5 support. I believe PyQt5 is also only available for python 3 under 14.04

Comment: Wops, I forgot it. Updating matplotlib from 1.3.1 to 1.5.3 solved the problem. Thank you.